# Storing each line of a text file into an array

Tags: c, arrays, file, line

I am trying to save each line of a text file into an array.
They way I am doing it and works fine so far is this :

```
char *lines[40];
char line[50];
int i = 0 ;
char* eof ;
while( (eof = fgets(line, 50, in)) != NULL )
{
    lines[i] = strdup(eof); /*Fills the array with line of the txt file one by one*/
    i++;
}
```

My text file has 40 lines , which I am accessing with a for loop

```
for( j = 0; j <= 39 ; j++)
{ /*Do something to each line*/}.
```

So far so good. My problem is that i define the size of the array **lines**
for the a text file that has 40 lines. I tried to count the lines and then define the size but I am getting **segmentation fault**.

My approach:

```
int count=1 ; char c ;
for (c = getc(in); c != EOF; c = getc(in))
    if (c == '\n') // Increment count if this character is newline
        count = count + 1;
printf("\nNUMBER OF LINES = %d \n",count); 

char* lines[count];
```

Any ideas ?

Comment: Allocate memory for the pointer array itself with `malloc`, when it reaches your limit extend it with `realloc` and update the limit...

Comment: Do we have a stock answer for this?  It gets asked approx. 3x/day.

Comment: @kata aside: remember that `fgets` will keep any `newline` entered, at the end of `line`.

Comment: @SteveSummit in a way, yes.  Googling the exact title gives: 'About 1,500,000 results'.

Comment: Just checking as this is not a [mcve]: you *do* remember to rewind the file back to the start before running the second part, right? Without, the very first `fgets` will fail and all of your `lines` contents are undefined.

Comment: Use a linked list.

Comment: Currently, you are allocating no memory. `char* lines[count];` creates an array of pointers, but there is no memory allocated. You should use malloc/realloc of that. Note: Do not forget to free you allocated memory after you are done!

Comment: @MartinEttl please look up `strdup`, what it does.

Comment: kata - I used the exact code you show above to get line count, with a file containing more than 1000 lines, with some lines 4000 char long.  The problem is not there.  So, that suggests the seg fault is likely due to the way you are allocating memory.  You may be attempting to write long line to a short buffer.

Comment: I really think you are using the wrong data structure for the task. I'd use a linked list of pointers to char and dynamically allocate enough bytes for each line as you read the file. You can then display the contents / search by walking the the list. Do you need random access to each line or is a linear search sufficient?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways to approach this problem. Either declare a static 2D array or char (e.g. `char lines[40][50] = {{""}};`) or declare a *pointer to array of type char [50]*, which is probably the easiest for dynamic allocation. With that approach you only need a single allocation. With constant `MAXL = 40` and `MAXC = 50`, you simply need:

```
char (*lines)[MAXC] = NULL;
...
lines = malloc (MAXL * sizeof *lines);
```

Reading each line with `fgets` is a simple task of:

```
while (i < MAXL && fgets (lines[i], MAXC, fp)) {...
```

When you are done, all you need to do is `free (lines);` Putting the pieces together, you can do something like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

enum { MAXL = 40, MAXC = 50 };

int main (int argc, char **argv) {

    char (*lines)[MAXC] = NULL; /* pointer to array of type char [MAXC] */
    int i, n = 0;
    FILE *fp = argc > 1 ? fopen (argv[1], "r") : stdin;

    if (!fp) {  /* valdiate file open for reading */
        fprintf (stderr, "error: file open failed '%s'.\n", argv[1]);
        return 1;
    }

    if (!(lines = malloc (MAXL * sizeof *lines))) { /* allocate MAXL arrays */
        fprintf (stderr, "error: virtual memory exhausted 'lines'.\n");
        return 1;
    }

    while (n < MAXL && fgets (lines[n], MAXC, fp)) { /* read each line */
        char *p = lines[n];                  /* assign pointer */
        for (; *p && *p != '\n'; p++) {}     /* find 1st '\n'  */
        *p = 0, n++;                         /* nul-termiante  */
    }
    if (fp != stdin) fclose (fp);   /* close file if not stdin */

    /* print lines */
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) printf (" line[%2d] : '%s'\n", i + 1, lines[i]);

    free (lines);   /* free allocated memory */

    return 0;
}
```

*note:* you will also want to check to see if the whole line was read by `fgets` each time. (say you had a long line of more than 38 chars in the file). You do this by checking  whether `*p` is `'\n'` before overwriting with the *nul-terminating* character. (e.g. `if (*p != '\n') { int c; while ((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF) {} }`). That insures the next read with `fgets` will begin with the next line, instead of the remaining characters in the current line.

To include the check you could do something similar to the following (*note:* I changed the read loop counter from `i` to `n` to eliminate the need for assigning `n = i;` following the read loop).

```
    while (n < MAXL && fgets (lines[n], MAXC, fp)) { /* read each line */
        char *p = lines[n];                 /* assign pointer  */
        for (; *p && *p != '\n'; p++) {}    /* find 1st '\n'   */
        if (*p != '\n') {                   /* check line read */
            int c;  /* discard remainder of line with getchar  */
            while ((c = fgetc (fp)) != '\n' && c != EOF) {}
        }
        *p = 0, n++;                        /* nul-termiante   */
    }
```

It is up to you whether you discard or keep the remainder of lines that exceed the length of your array. However, it is a good idea to always check. (the lines of text in my example input below are limited to 17-chars so there was no possibility of a long line, but you generally cannot guarantee the line length.

**Example Input**

```
$ cat dat/40lines.txt
line of text -  1
line of text -  2
line of text -  3
line of text -  4
line of text -  5
line of text -  6
...
line of text - 38
line of text - 39
line of text - 40
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/fgets_ptr2array <dat/40lines.txt
 line[ 1] : 'line of text -  1'
 line[ 2] : 'line of text -  2'
 line[ 3] : 'line of text -  3'
 line[ 4] : 'line of text -  4'
 line[ 5] : 'line of text -  5'
 line[ 6] : 'line of text -  6'
...
 line[38] : 'line of text - 38'
 line[39] : 'line of text - 39'
 line[40] : 'line of text - 40'
```

Now include a the length check in code and add a long line to the input, e.g.:

```
$ cat dat/40lines+long.txt
line of text -  1
line of text -  2
line of text -  3 + 123456789 123456789 123456789 123456789 65->|
line of text -  4
...
```

Rerun the program and you can confirm you have now protected against long lines in the file mucking up your sequential read of lines from the file.

---

**Dynamically Reallocating `lines`**

If you have an unknown number of lines in your file and you reach your initial allocation of `40` in `lines`, then all you need do to keep reading additional lines is `realloc` storage for `lines`. For example:

```
    int i, n = 0, maxl = MAXL;
    ...
    while (fgets (lines[n], MAXC, fp)) {     /* read each line */
        char *p = lines[n];                  /* assign pointer */
        for (; *p && *p != '\n'; p++) {}     /* find 1st '\n'  */
        *p = 0;                              /* nul-termiante  */
        if (++n == maxl) { /* if limit reached, realloc lines  */
            void *tmp = realloc (lines, 2 * maxl * sizeof *lines);
            if (!tmp) {     /* validate realloc succeeded */
                fprintf (stderr, "error: realloc - virtual memory exhausted.\n");
                break;      /* on failure, exit with existing data */
            }
            lines = tmp;    /* assign reallocated block to lines */
            maxl *= 2;      /* update maxl to reflect new size */
        }
    }
```

Now it doesn't matter how many lines are in your file, you will simply keep reallocating `lines` until your entire files is read, or you run out of memory. (note: currently the code reallocates twice the current memory for `lines` on each reallocation. You are free to add as much or as little as you like. For example, you could allocate `maxl + 40` to simply allocate `40` more lines each time.

**Edit In Response To Comment Inquiry**

If you do want to use a fixed increase in the number of `lines` rather than scaling by some factor, you must allocate for a fixed number of additional `lines` (the increase times `sizeof *lines`), you can't simple add `40` bytes, e.g.

```
        void *tmp = realloc (lines, (maxl + 40) * sizeof *lines);
            if (!tmp) {     /* validate realloc succeeded */
                fprintf (stderr, "error: realloc - virtual memory exhausted.\n");
                break;      /* on failure, exit with existing data */
            }
            lines = tmp;    /* assign reallocated block to lines */
            maxl += 40;     /* update maxl to reflect new size */
        }
```

Recall, `lines` is a *pointer-to-array* of `char[50]`, so for each additional line you want to allocate, you must allocate storage for 50-char (e.g. `sizeof *lines`), so the fixed increase by 40 lines will be `realloc (lines, (maxl + 40) * sizeof *lines);`, then you must accurately update your max-lines-allocated count (`maxl`) to reflect the increase of `40` lines, e.g. `maxl += 40;`.

**Example Input**

```
$ cat dat/80lines.txt
line of text -  1
line of text -  2
...
line of text - 79
line of text - 80
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/fgets_ptr2array_realloc <dat/80lines.txt
 line[ 1] : 'line of text -  1'
 line[ 2] : 'line of text -  2'
...
 line[79] : 'line of text - 79'
 line[80] : 'line of text - 80'
```

Look it over and let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: what if my text file has more than 40 lines ? :/

Comment: You are already protected by `while (n < MAXL && fgets (lines[n], MAXC, fp))`. When you have read `40` lines (e.g. line indexes `0-39`) and try and read line `41`, `n == MAXL` and the loop exits.

Comment: If you are saying you want to read more than `40`, then `realloc` lines and keep going. I'll add an example.

Comment: Now, what can i do to operate these lines ? lets say we want to access every lines[i] string

Comment: Do the same thing I did to `printf` them. `for (i = 0; i < n; i++) { do whatever with lines[i]; }`. That is the beauty of having all lines stored in memory. (note: I also updated `getchar()` to `fgetc (fp)` to handle trimming the end of lines when reading from a file as well as from `stdin` - original oversight `:)`

Comment: Works fine !!! I did the same but a little typo messed up my code !! I am so bad, thanks!!

Comment: Glad it helped. Make sure you understand what's going on with each line, each char, of the code. There is a whole lot subtle C packed into this deceptively small example. It is covering everything from pre-increment operator use `(++n == maxl)`, basic pointer handling, walking a string with `p` to find the `'\n'`,  analyzing whether `fgets` read the entire line, and what to do if it didn't, proper use of a `tmp` pointer with `realloc` to prevent losing your original content and causing a mem-leak if `realloc` fails, etc.. Good luck with your coding.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin I try to expand allocated memory linearly, as you suggested with `maxl + 40` (i.e., `void *tmp = realloc (lines, maxl + 40);`) but I get `double free or corruption (out)` error. What I do wrong?

Comment: @Andrej That tells me that `lines` was not assigned the value of `tmp` after the last `realloc` or `lines` was not something originally allocated with `malloc` or `realloc` to begin with. Recall that `realloc` performs a `free()` on the pointer after it has allocated a new block and copied the original information to the new block. If you don't assign `lines=tmp;` after a `realloc` then `lines` will be left pointing to a block that has already been freed and then next call to `realloc` will result in the *double-free* or corruption.

Comment: @Andrej, post your code to pastebin.com or suse.paste.com and post a comment below with the link and I'll take a look.

Comment: @Andrej Your problem is here `maxl + 40` and here `maxl *= 2;`. It is fine if you want to add a fixed `40` rows each reallocation, but then you need to reallocate `realloc (lines, (maxl + 40) * sizeof *lines);` and update your `maxl` to match, e.g. `maxl += 40;` instead of `maxl *= 2;` (which doubles `maxl` each time `:)` Also, `MAXC = 50`, make sure your lines can never exceed `48` chars (+2 for `'\n'` and `'\0'`). Better `MAXC = 1024` or more. (*don't skimp on buffer size).

Comment: @Andrej see: [pastebin fixed](http://susepaste.org/7009461), expires: Sun May 19 02:26:55 CDT 2019.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin I really appreciate your time.

Comment: Glad it helped. I also dropped a reply to the link above showing how to user `string.h` and `strcspn` to trim the `'\n'` included in the buffer by `fgets`. That is a bit more "formal" than simply using a pointer and a `for` loop to scan to the end of string and overwrite the `'\n'` with `0`. Both accomplish the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

As an aside, I tested the exact code you show above to get line count (by counting newline characters), on a file containing more than 1000 lines, and with some lines 4000 char long. The problem is not there. 
The *seg fault* is therefore likely due to the way you are allocating memory for each line buffer. You may be attempting to write a long line to a short buffer. (maybe I missed it in your post, but could not find where you addressed line length?)

Two things useful when allocating memory for storing strings in a file are number of lines, and the maximum line length in the file.  These can be used to create the array of `char` arrays.

You can get both line count and longest line by looping on `fgets(...)`: (a variation on your theme, essentially letting `fgets` find the newlines)

```
int countLines(FILE *fp, int *longest)
{
    int i=0;
    int max = 0;
    char line[4095];  // max for C99 strings
    *longest = max;
    while(fgets(line, 4095, fp))
    {
        max = strlen(line); 
        if(max > *longest) *longest = max;//record longest
        i++;//track line count
    }
    return i;
}
int main(void)
{
    int longest;
    char **strArr = {0};
    FILE *fp = fopen("C:\\dev\\play\\text.txt", "r");
    if(fp)
    {
        int count = countLines(fp, &longest);
        printf("%d", count);
        GetKey();
    }
    // use count and longest to create memory
    strArr = create2D(strArr, count, longest);
    if(strArr)
    {
       //use strArr ...
       //free strArr
       free2D(strArr, lines);
    }
    ......and so on
    return 0;   
}

char ** create2D(char **a, int lines, int longest)
{
    int i;
    a = malloc(lines*sizeof(char *));
    if(!a) return NULL;
    {
        for(i=0;i<lines;i++)
        {
            a[i] = malloc(longest+1);
            if(!a[i]) return NULL;
        }
    }
    return a;
}

void free2D(char **a, int lines)
{
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<lines;i++)
    {
        if(a[i]) free(a[i]);
    }
    if(a) free(a);
}
```

Comment: @kata any line of length greater than 50 will be broken and read as at least 2 lines: counting the `newlines` won't tell you this.

Comment: @WeatherVane - did you meant to post this comment here?

Comment: Yes, because of your first para.

Comment: Line length is addressed in `fgets(line, 50, in)`.

Comment: @WeatherVane - can you clarify please.  When I ran the exact OP code (i.e. counting newlines) I was able to accurately count lines longer than 50 (over 4000) without a problem.

Comment: A line of length, say, 60, will deliver one `newline` when read char by char, but will be read by `fgets` as two lines. `fgets` does not throw away the rest of the line.