# How to randomize and remove whitespace from input redirection in C

Tags: c, regex, command-line-arguments

I want to pass a text file using input redirection to my program as a command line argument. I would then like the words in this to be **randomly** printed and **whitespace** removed.

I would like to run the program as

```
foo <dict.txt
```

*dict.txt* will contain various words, such as

```
camel penguin tiger chicken
```

I can currently print the contents of dict.txt using

```
    char line[100];

    while(scanf("%[^\n]%*c", &line) == 1) {
        printf("%s\n",line);
```

this would output

```
camel penguin tiger chicken
```

I would like it to be random and whitespace removed such as

```
penguinchickencameltiger
```

For the most part I am not sure how to approach it, I was thinking of putting it into an array and somehow randomizing it, or using regular expressions but I am not familiar with how to apply these.

Thanks in advance, I am a relatively new coder.

Comment: The `dict.txt` example you posted appears to be a single line. Is that the case, or is each word on a new line? Can you post a [mcve] that reproduces the problem?

Comment: Yes, you'd read the words into a static array or [a dynamic one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36801833/storing-each-line-of-a-text-file-into-an-array), then apply [Fisher-Yates shuffle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3343797/is-this-c-implementation-of-fisher-yates-shuffle-correct), then print the elements in the shuffled order without intervening spaces.

Comment: Note that if you use redirection `foo <dict.txt`, the program gets no command line argument (other than the program name).  Or you can get a command line argument `foo dict.txt` and then open and process the file.